# To what extent a song's words determine its music

Tags: voice, composition

Imagine you want to compose music for a song and only for a single instrument: the piano. What are the guiding principles? How much freedom does one have in this process?

My reason for asking this question is partly curiosity and partly because I've recently been learning singing and I think if I know what rules guide the process of associating musical notes to the lyrics, I can match my voice to the pitch with more ease.

Case in point let's take a look at the song Shadow of Your Smile.
[image]
The first and the second verse follow a similar pattern but in the first, at "smile" the note drops to C sharp, but in the second, at "dreams" it drops to E. What causes this difference? If I swap the notes it will sound off so my question is how can one determine the notes without lots of trial and error?

Comment: are you asking about the lyrics or about the melody? Like thinking purely melodically just study basic harmonies and chord progressions and fit the melody to those. If you're talking about what notes correspond to what words, that's purely subjective and anyone can argue for anything.

Comment: Sorry, there isn't really any guidance here. There are some popular techniques related to setting words to music, but they mostly focus on the rhythm, not the notes chosen. Often a higher note will be used on an important word and notes may be higher or lower based on the sound of the word itself, but there's nothing to tell you exactly which note a word is meant to be sung at except the sheet music.

Comment: There's such a thing as [word painting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_painting) (or tone painting for music without lyrics, I guess), which makes the melody notes fit the lyrics better, but I'm not quite sure if that's what you're going for. At any rate, it seems rare in modern music and much more common in classical music.

Comment: "To what extent a songs lyrics determine it music" for a single instrument. If the answer to this is opinion based then the answer to "Does a given music match a given song" must be opinion based too.

Answer (score -1):

music is a creative process - so there are no rules other than "it should sound pretty good".  music theory tries to capture some the the common ways composers do their thing.  but nobody has to follow those rules when writing their song.

but i'd say lyrics can definitely send the music in certain directions at least.  Lyrics are poetry so...

- there are syllables that can contribute to the rhythm.
- at the end of a phrase there is a pause that music can fill or punctuate.
- Poetry has intonation (how it's read/sung), so that can lead to increases/decreases in volume and
- changes in pitch as your voice naturally goes up or down saying certain things.

but that's just something you can do.  not rules.